# MongoDb Node.js drivder - Do I have to close and open connection for each operation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am reading [node.js mongodb driver tutorial](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/tutorials/connect/.)

On the sample code below from the tutorial, it closes the client just after it finishes to do whatever it wants to do.

In case of web-server that constantly interacts with mongo, Is it really expected to reconnect to MongoDB and then close the connection with this procedure each time a request is coming? suggestions for better implementations are welcomed :)

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018/?replicaSet=foo';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'myproject';

// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(url);

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
client.connect(function(err) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");

  const db = client.db(dbName);

  client.close();
});
```

Comment: I know mongoose, i want to explore the native driver for now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, it uses a connection pool there is no need to close the connection.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"); 
var db = 'mongodb://localhost/dataBaseName';
mongoose.connect(db, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
fs.readdirSync(__dirname + "/models").forEach(function (filename) {
    if (~filename.indexOf(".js")) require(__dirname + "/models/" + filename);
});

mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);
```

Comment: where `autoIncrement` came from?

Comment: Sorry just remove it, It is for my module.

Comment: There is no need for open and close connections.

Answer (score -1):

Not necessary to close and open connection multiple times in same runtime. Connect once when app starts.